# Reading a text file accurately in Python

Tags: python, numpy, txt

I am trying to read a `.txt` file. However, the output is in strings and I don't get the actual array. I present the current and expected outputs below.

```
import numpy as np
with open('Test.txt') as f:
    A = f.readlines()
    print(A)
```

The current output is

```
['[array([[1.7],\n', '       [2.8],\n', '       [3.9],\n', '       [5.2]])]']
```

The expected output is

```
[array([[1.7],
       [2.8],
       [3.9],
       [5.2]])]
```

Comment: It looks like what you have here is the string representation of a numpy array. As far as I know, there is no ready-made function in numpy to parse this back into an array.  If possible, your best bet is probably to fix this issue "upstream" by choosing a better format for writing the array into the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### By using `regex` and [ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) :

```
import re
import ast

#Your output
s = ['[array([[1.7],\n', '       [2.8],\n', '       [3.9],\n', '       [5.2]])]']

#Join them
s = ' '.join(s)

#Find the list in string by regex
s  = re.findall("\((\[[\w\W]*\])\)",s)

#Convert string to list
ast.literal_eval(s[0])
```

Output:

```
[[1.7], [2.8], [3.9], [5.2]]
```

#### By using `regex` and `eval` :

```
import re

#Your output
s = ['[array([[1.7],\n', '       [2.8],\n', '       [3.9],\n', '       [5.2]])]']

#Join them
s = ' '.join(s)

#Find the list in string by regex
s  = re.findall("\((\[[\w\W]*\])\)",s)

#Convert string to list
eval(s[0])
```

Output:

```
[[1.7], [2.8], [3.9], [5.2]]
```

Comment: use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval), normal eval is susceptible to code injection attacks, since the file is not protected in any way.